# Java MouseListener creating a Button without JButton

Tags: java, mouselistener

I want to create a pause screen for my mini-game. For that, you press the esc button, and a picture will appear with the buttons: Resume, Options and Exit. In my MouseInput-class, is the mousePressed method. I just want, that if I press the mouse at the location of the button, that something happens. I've already made the half, but I don't know the rest. The method would now only use a corner of the box.(Sorry if my english is bad)

The Menu should look like this (its a screenshot from the "game".)
http://puu.sh/e1b6v/79682e61f4.PNG

[image]

```
package de.dragonbone.rpg.input;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class MouseInput implements MouseListener {

int mx;
int my;

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    mx = e.getX();
    my = e.getY();

    if (mx == 154 && my == 160) {
        System.out.println("Resume");
    }

    System.out.println("X= " + mx + "  Y= " + my);
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

}
```

Comment: When you draw the menu, do you use shapes like RoundRectangle2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the location should be a range not a point.

Example of range:

```
if (mx >= 154 || mx<=200 && my >= 160 && my<= 200) {
    System.out.println("Resume");
}
```

Comment: When you write `if (mx == 154 && my == 160)`, the program checks if the mouse pressed the exact point (154, 160). Like the answer says, you need to check a range of points so the program checks wheter if a point on the whole area of the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add mouselistener to the buttons.

```
class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
{
     @Override
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
     {
        JButton jb=(JButton)me.getSource();
        String str=jb.getActionCommand();
        if(str.equals("Resume"))
          System.out.println("Resumed");
        .....
        .....
     }
}
JButton resume=new JButton("Resume");
resume.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
```